# How to test infinite scroll in a table?

Tags: protractor

I am testing Infinite scrolling in my angular application. The scroll is part of a table in the main page. The main page doesn't have any scroll bar of its own and if I hover the mouse over the table and scroll more elements will be loaded.

Initially, 50 rows are displayed on the screen out of which only 10 are visible on the table. On scrolling to the last element, the next 50 will be loaded in the UI. This will be continued until all the elements are retrieved.

I tried clicking on the first row of the table and used scroll

dashboard.Row1.click()
        browser.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)");

This doesn't scroll the table. I am not sure if this is the right approach to solve the problem. I also tried using offset but it didn't help either

This is my HTML:

```
<tbody infinite-scroll="$ctrl.loadInventories()" infinite-scroll-container="'.table-wrapper'" md-body="" class="md-body ng-isolate-scope">
<!-- ngRepeat: data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder -->
<tr class="" ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder" style="">

<!-- ngRepeat: data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder -->
<tr class="" ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder" style="">

<!-- ngRepeat: data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder -->
<tr class="" ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder" style="">

<!-- ngRepeat: data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder -->
<tr class="" ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.inventories | orderBy: myOrder" style="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try scrolling to the last row of the table using [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).  It would be something like

```
const tableRows = element.all(by.css('tbody tr'));
browser.executeScript(e => e.scrollIntoView(), tableRows.last());
```

Or more compactly, perhaps less readable

```
browser.executeScript(e => e.scrollIntoView(), $$('tbody tr').last());
```

Comment: I tried scrollIntoView. In my app, there is a load time to load the next 50 rows . ScrollIntoView is loading only the next 50 rows and stopped execution. I tried using while loop and waitforangular. but still it doesn't actually fetch all the rows which may take like 8 or 9 full scrollintoview

Comment: I understand, yeah the times I've tested infinite scroll, I ended up looping the "scroll to bottom" action as many times as necessary to load everything, with a delay inside each loop to prepare for the next scroll.  That's how the user would do it, I don't know of a shortcut for the test (unless your app has a "results per page" setting you could crank up).

Comment: @Bin Hi Bin, if you this answer helped you would you mind accepting it using the tick on the left side. This way other users can quickly see if it worked if they search for the same issue